# Running Docker on Google Cloud Instance with data in gcsfuse-mounted Bucket

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, mount, gcsfuse

I am trying to run a Docker container to analyze data in a Google Cloud Bucket.

I have been able to successfully mount the Bucket using `gcsfuse`, and I tested that I could do things like create and delete files within the Bucket.

In order to be able to install other programs (and mount the bucket), I installed Docker (and didn't use the Docker-optimized instance option).  If I run Docker in interactive mode (without mounting a drive), it looks like it is working OK.

However, if I try to run Docker in interactive mode with the mounted drive (which is the gcsfuse-mounted Bucket), I get an error message:

```
user@instance:~/bucket-name/subfolder$ docker run -it -v /home/user/bucket-name:/mnt/bucket-name gcr.io/deepvariant-docker/deepvariant
docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/home/user/bucket-name': mkdir /home/user/bucket-name: file exists.
```

I hope that I am close to having this working: does anybody have any ideas about a relatively simple fix for this error message?

BTW, I realize that there are other ways to run DeepVariant on Google Cloud, but I am trying to makes things as similar as possible to what I am doing on AWS (plus, I may need to do some extra troubleshooting for analysis of one of my files).

Thank you very much for your help!

## ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

FYI, this is how I mounted the Bucket:

```
#mount directory: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/installing.md
export GCSFUSE_REPO=gcsfuse-`lsb_release -c -s`
echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt $GCSFUSE_REPO main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gcsfuse.list
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install gcsfuse

#restart and mount directory: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse
#NOTE: please make sure you are in your home directory (I encounter issues if I try to mount from /mnt)
mkdir [bucket-name]
gcsfuse -o allow_other --file-mode 777 --dir-mode 777 [bucket-name] ./[bucket-name]
```

and this is how I installed Docker:

```
#install Docker for Debian: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/debian/
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gnupg2 \
    software-properties-common
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo apt-key add -

sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y --allow-unauthenticated install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io

#fix Docker sock issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47854463/got-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-socket-at-uni
sudo usermod -a -G docker [user]
#have to restart after this
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone experiencing a similar error / issue - here is what worked for me. Steps I took:

1. First unmount the disk if it's already mounted: `sudo umount /mounted_folder`
2. Remount the disk using the below command, listing the credentials file to be used explicitly

```
sudo GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/home/user/credentials/example-asdf21b0af7.json gcsfuse -o allow_other bucket_name /mounted_folder
```

3. Should now be connected successfully without further errors :)

NOTE: This command needs to be run everytime after restarting the computer / VM. Formatting this into `fstab` could probably be done so one does not need to manually execute these steps upon each restart.

EXPLANATION: What I did here was explicitly specifying the credentials via a credentials JSON for the user / service account with appropriate access (Not explained here on how to get this but should be googl-able) and referring to that json in the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable option, as suggested by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39047673/10002593. The need for this environment variable option is likely due to `gcsfuse` not registering the same level of access as the activated acount in `gcloud config` for some reason.

Comment: the key was "-o allow_other" for me!

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out at least a partial solution to my problem:

As mentioned in [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/quickstart-docker), you also need to run `gcloud auth configure-docker`.

I found you also needed to exit and restart your instance, but this strictly solved the original error message for this post.

I think got a strange message, but perhaps that is more about the specific container.  So, I ran another test:

```
docker run -it -v /home/user/bucket-name:/mnt/bucket-name cwarden45/dnaseq-dependencies
```

This time, I got an error message about storage space on the instance (to be able to download and run the Docker container).  So, I went back and created a new instance with a larger local hard drive:

**1)** From the Google Cloud Console, I selected "Compute Instance" and "VM instances"

**2)** I clicked "create instance" (similar to before)

**3)** I select "change" under "boot disk"

**4)** I set size to **300 GB** instead of 10 GB (currently, towards bottom-right, under "Size (GB)")

Similar to before, I choose 8 vCPUs for the "Machine type", I selected "Allow full access to all Cloud APIs" under "Identity and API access", and I checked boxes for both "Allow HTTP traffic" and "Allow HTTPS traffic" (under "Firewall").

I am **not** selecting "Deploy a container image to this VM instance," which I believe is how I got Docker installed with "sudo" to be able to install gcsfuse.

I also have to call this a "**parital**" solution because this allows me to run the Docker container successfully in interactive mode, **but the mounted bucket appears empty within Docker**.

For another project, I noticed that executables could work if I installed them on the local hard drive under /opt, but not if I tried to install them on my bucket (in order to save the installation time for those programs each time).  On AWS, I believe I needed to use EFS storage instead of S3 storage to do something similar, but I will keep learning more about using the Google Cloud Bucket for mounted storage / analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Also, it is a different issue, but I noticed that I could fix an issue with running exectuable files from the bucket from changing the command from `gcsfuse [bucket-name] ./[bucket-name]` to `gcsfuse --file-mode 777 --dir-mode 777 [bucket-name] ./[bucket-name]` (and I changed the example code accordingly)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed more recently that the set of commands above is no longer sufficient to be able to have a functional directory (I can't add or edit files, for example).

Based upon [this discussion](https://serverfault.com/questions/750640/permission-errors-using-gcsfuse-as-nonroot-user-on-google-compute-instance), I thought that I needed to add the `-o allow_other` parameter.

However, if that is all I do, I get the following error message

```
fusermount: option allow_other only allowed if 'user_allow_other' is set in /etc/fuse.conf
```

I can resolve that error message if I uncomment the corresponding line in that file.  However, that still doesn't resolve having the right file permissions in the mounted directory.

So, I then tried editing my `/etc/fstab` file, by adding the following entry

```
[bucket-name] /home/[username]/[bucket-name] gcsfuse rw,allow_other,file_mode=777,dir_mode=777
```

I am also accordingly editing the content at the top (for whatever seems like it might help).

**Also, please note that this was not a Docker-specific issue.**  This was necessary to essentially do anything within the bucket.  Plus, I haven't actually solved this new problem.

For example, I still can't create files as root, after changing to the superuser via `sudo su -` (as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617850/changing-from-user-to-superuser))